# blog containter not showing proper background

Tags: php, css, html, containers

I'd like for my blog container to have a separate background from the page as a whole. However, it is taking on wood.png as a background not bg.png.
I'm using the following:

CSS

```
body {
 background: url('img/bg.png') repeat;
}
.above {
 background: url('img/wood.png') repeat;
 width: 100%;
}
#blog-header {
 background: url('img/wood.png') repeat; 
 height: 160px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#blog-container {
 background: url('img/bg.png') repeat;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 960px;
}
#blog {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 80px;
 position: relative;
 width: 620px;
}
```

HTML/PHP

```
<body>
<div class="above">
 <div id="blog-header">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Urban Palate logo" id="logo" /></a>
   </div><!-- end logo -->
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/?page_id=7"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="Urban Palate intro" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="/?page_id=12"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio.png" alt="Urban Palate portfolio" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="/?page_id=15"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog.png" alt="Urban Palate blog" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="/?page_id=10"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact.png" alt="Urban Palate contact" /></a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   </div><!-- end blog-header -->
   <div id="blog-container">
    <div id="blog">
     <div id="post">
       //content
     </div><!-- end post -->
    </div><!-- end blog -->
   </div><!-- end blog-container -->
```

Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

ETA: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @AdamPlocher Sorry, original question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element is containing floating element, the wrapping element then needs a `overflow:auto` or a `clear:both;` to get the height it needs to add background to it.

In your case you can add either the `overflow:auto` or the `clear:both` to `#blog-container` or you can add it as a separate class as shown below:

Here's a few nice lines you can use to add a clearfix declaration to your css, the you can add that class to any element that has floating elements in it:

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

The clearfix is taken from: [Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

And here is an extra nice question talking about the clearfix differences: [which method of clearfix is best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) (check answer two)

Comment: Don't really need a `clear:both`; `overflow:auto` is enough to make the container expand to contain it's floated children.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set some padding on your body (or set the div width to 95% instead of 100%).  It looks like the div is going to take up the full width of the screen.